# separate number from string and add numbers using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

This is my code !!

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1,008$','4,000$','6,000$','10,00$','8,00$','45 €','45 €']})
```

Data cleaning is also done.

```
    result2 = df2['A'].str.replace(',','.')
    result2 = result2.str.replace('$','')
    result2 = result2.str.replace('€','')
    print (result2)
```

which gives me output like this

```
In [11]: result2
Out[11]: 
0    1.008
1    4.000
2    6.000
3    10.00
4     8.00
5       45
6      45 
Name: A, dtype: object
```

but my objective is to add amount of different currencies together , that is the output should be like this

```
Your amount in dollar is "29.008"
your amount in euros is "90"
```

i am not very good at python , please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
df2.A.str.replace(',', '.').str.extract(
    '^(?P<Value>.*)(?P<Currency>\D)$', expand=True
).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').groupby('Currency').Value.sum()

Currency
$    29.008
€    90.000
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 2**

```
v = pd.to_numeric(df2.A.str[:-1].str.replace(',', '.'))
c = df2.A.str[-1]

v.groupby(c).sum()

A
$    29.008
€    90.000
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

---

**Option 3**

```
d = {'$': 'dollar', '€': 'euro'}

v = pd.to_numeric(df2.A.str[:-1].str.replace(',', '.'))
c = df2.A.str[-1].map(d)

v.groupby(c).sum()

A
dollar    29.008
euro      90.000
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks !! 
but i am getting error while running this .. 
TypeError : str_extract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'

Comment: You're using an old version of pandas.  You can leave that out.

Comment: yes , updated pandas now !!! Thanks a lot !!!

but for option 1 and 2 i am getting same error 
'ValueError: Unable to parse string "45 \xe2\x82" at position 5\n'

Comment: for option 1, i am getting output like this 
"Currency
$    1.0084.0006.00010.008.00
�                    45 �45 �"

Comment: Is it the same data as you presented above?

Comment: Are you sure that you've got a list of strings in your constructor?  I copied and pasted your code above.   Can you copy and paste your own code above, then run one of my options again

Comment: import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1,008$','4,000$','6,000$','10,00$','8,00$','45 €','45 €']})

df2.A.str.replace(',', '.').str.extract('^(?P<Value>.*)(?P<Currency>\D)$', expand=True).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore').groupby('Currency').Value.sum()

v = pd.to_numeric(df2.A.str[:-1].str.replace(',', '.'))
c = df2.A.str[-1]

v.groupby(c).sum()

d = {'$': 'dollar', '€': 'euro'}

v = pd.to_numeric(df2.A.str[:-1].str.replace(',', '.'))
c = df2.A.str[-1].map(d)

v.groupby(c).sum()



this is the code